# Is it possible to load nested navigation properties using EntityEntry.Reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Take these example classes:

```
class TemplatePart
{
    public PartStock stock {get; set;}
    ...other POCOs
}

class PartStock
{
    public Part part {get; set;}
    ...other POCOs
}

class Part
{
    public PartName name {get; set;}
    ...other POCOs
}
```

Now, suppose I already have an entity for a `TemplatePart`.  I can do this:

```
var entry = context.Entry(templatePart);
entry.Reference(x => x.PartStock).Load();
```

That would load the navigation property for the `PartStock`.  But how do I do this:

```
entry.Reference(x => x.PartStock.Part).Load();
```

That produces an exception:

> The expression 'x => x.PartStock.Part' is not a valid property
>   expression. The expression should represent a simple property access:
>   't => t.MyProperty'. Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

Is there some alternative to this that still uses the `entry` I already have?  I don't want to have to reload the whole thing again using `Include` if I don't have to.

I am using EntityFramework Core 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of directly calling `Load` method, you could use a combination of `Query()`, `Include` / `ThenInclude` and `Load` methods:

```
entry.Reference(x => x.PartStock)
    .Query()
    .Include(x => x.Part)
    .Load();
```

Comment: What about if we are getting the reference via a string property name?  The resulting IQueryable is not generic (we don't know the type ahead of time) and this doesn't have an Include extension method.

Comment: Just figured out you can just use `dynamic`.  As in, `Reference<dynamic>("propertyName").Query()`.   Now this `IQueryable<dynamic>` has the extension method `Include()` which can also be used with a property string name.

Comment: You've been of great help.