# How to access chained/nested property in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following classes:

```
public class Vehicle{
    public Engine TurboV6 { get; set; }

public class Engine{
    public Cylinder Core { get; set; }

public class Cylinder{
    public double? Capacity { get; set; }
```

And I have configured the owned entities as below in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
                .OwnsOne(
                    v => v.TurboV6, e=> {
                        e.OwnsOne(e => e.Core);
                    });
```

**The Problem**

When I tried to save a null value in the owned entity like `v.TurboV6.Core = null;` EF Core does not save null value in the `Vehicle.TurboV6.Core.Capacity` as null, instead the previous value persists in the database. I assume this is caused by a problem in EF Core's change tracking.

I tried to overcome this with :

```
vContext = DbContext.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle());
vContext.Property(v => v.TurboV6.Core.Capacity).IsModified = true;
```

Take note that `vContext` is `EntityEntry<Vehicle>` type, not `DbContext`.

Similar to this question: [Nested navigation properties using entity entry reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675380/is-it-possible-to-load-nested-navigation-properties-using-entityentry-reference) ,

When I access the code below:

```
vContext.Property(v => v.TurboV6.Core.Capacity).IsModified = true;
```

I got an error message saying

> System.ArgumentException : The expression 'v => v.TurboV6.Core.Capacity' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'propertyAccessExpression')

I am using EF Core 2.2.6

Is it possible to map chained property like above? Have I missed anything?
If yes, how do I do so?

Thank you

Comment: Can you get/use a `EntityEntry<Capacity>` instead and then use the `.Property()` method as you want?

Comment: Why not using classic FK code first approach ?

Comment: [DbContext doesn't have a Property() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext?view=efcore-3.1). Why are you using `vContext.Property(v => v.TurboV6.Core.Capacity)` at all instead of working with objects?

Comment: @Progman, I only have access to `EntityEntry<Vehicle>`. How do I get `EntityEntry<Capacity>`?

Comment: @hunterex why do you want any of this? None of the tutorials tries to use the internal API methods - there's no need for it, unless you want to build extensions for EF Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I need to explicitly set `v.TurboV6.Core.Capacity` nullable property as modified so the EF Core would save the null value when I update  `v.TurboV6.Core.Capacity` as null

Comment: Again, why do it like this? And what is `vContext` ? The simple way shown in all tutorials is to simply load the object, modify it, and call `SaveChanges` at the end

Comment: @hunterex Have you disabled the change tracker for these entities? If so, why? Please [edit] your question with a more detailed description of your problem and what you are trying to do. It sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Again, DbContext doesn't have a `Properties` method which means `vContext` is your own class, or you created an extension method that calls [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef?view=efcore-3.1) using extension syntax. Which isn't necessary for DbSets. The question you linked to isn't about chained properties (there are no chained properties), it's about *eager loading* of related entities - that's what `Include` does. If you *don't* need eager loading, EF Core will load related entities using lazy loading as needed

Comment: All this means you've done a *lot* to disable the built-in functionality and put different APIs on top of EF Core itself. We can only guess what those changes were: I guessed you aren't using DbContext, Progman guessed you disabled change tracking. We can't guess what's wrong with the code itself though.

Comment: @hunterex Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @hunterex  From [Current Limitations](When I tried to save a null value in the owned entity like v.TurboV6.Core = null; the EF Core does not save null value in the Vehicle.TurboV6.Core.Capacity as null) `Reference navigations to owned entity types cannot be null unless they are explicitly mapped to a separate table from the owner`. Post a *complete but minimal* example that reproduces the problem. Don't force people to guess bit by bit from partial information

Comment: @hunterex if `vcontext` is actually a new entry, not a context, why should it have any value other than `null`? This wouldn't make sense unless you've defined default values for the columns which you *don't* want to use, but don't want to disable either. Frankly, this is a bad table design that can't be fixed by EF Core. Why did you use such a design in the first place? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why would a `Vehicle` table contain both default values for Engine columns *and* explicitly set them to null?

Answer (score 2):

`TurboV6` and `Core` are *reference navigation* properties, so they must be accessed through [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1.reference?view=efcore-3.1) method. The nested entity entry is accessible through [TargetEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.referenceentry-2.targetentry?view=efcore-3.1) property. Repeat that until you get to the desired level entry on which you can use `Property` method.

Something like this:

```cs
vContext
    .Reference(e => e.TurboV6).TargetEntry
    .Reference(e => e.Core).TargetEntry
    .Property(e => e.Capacity).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the *real* problem. The OP wants to set `Core` to `null` and get all owned type columns to change to `null`. Which should *already* be null since the `vContext` value represents a new entry

Comment: I've edited the question to try to make it readable and it looks like an XYZ problem - the OP tried to create columns *with* default values and still store `null` to them by default. That's the Y - no idea what X caused such a design. When that didn't work (because the property is already NULL in a new entity),  the OP tried to explicitly mark the properties as `Modified`. That's the Z, which also failed. Or is that an XYZZ1?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could be, I didn't follow the link, so this answers the direct question "How to access chained/nested property in EF Core 2.2" and `vContext.Property(v => v.TurboV6.Core.Capacity).IsModified = true;`. If the real problem is different, then they have to formulate different question.

Comment: Like asking a customer for the real requirements

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Haha, indeed!